# using the exmple of google drive sdk for read spreadsheet

Tags: c#, .net, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I am trying to use the google drive sdk exmple for read spread sheet.

when I am opening the example I am getting this error: "unhandled excption has occured......... returned unexpected result"404"

I am doing the following things:
1) in the login section I am entering my user name and password correctly (validate it a couple of times that it is correct)
2) go to tab :"Selected SpreadSheet". then the error comes up

Comment: Insert links in your question to clarify what you're referring to.

Comment: I am taliking such as this question I ask. however I am getting the an error:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/725627/accessing-google-spreadsheets-with-c-sharp-using-google-data-api

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are experiencing is similar to this question: [Google drive API to C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33126415/google-drive-api-to-c-sharp/34668142#34668142)

You can no longer log into Google Spreadsheets with the old user credentials (username/password only). You need to use OAuth 2.0 now (which requires you to create an app and credentials at [console.developers.google.com](https://console.developers.google.com)).

You can use the example below for the authentication logic, and use the logic in the logic found in this question to actually manipulate the file: 
[Accessing Google Spreadsheets with C# using Google Data API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/725627/accessing-google-spreadsheets-with-c-sharp-using-google-data-api)

Here is my answer to the linked question in case it gets deleted in the future:

---

This example requires you to use the following nuget packages and their dependencies:

- Google.GData.Spreadsheets

Also, you must go to https://console.developers.google.com and register your application and create credentials for it so you can enter your CLIENT_ID and CLIENT_SECRET.

This is the documentation I used to put together this example: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Google.GData.Client;
using Google.GData.Spreadsheets;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string CLIENT_ID = "YOUR_CLIENT_ID";
            string CLIENT_SECRET = "YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET";
            string SCOPE = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds https://docs.google.com/feeds";
            string REDIRECT_URI = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob";

            OAuth2Parameters parameters = new OAuth2Parameters();

            parameters.ClientId = CLIENT_ID;
            parameters.ClientSecret = CLIENT_SECRET;
            parameters.RedirectUri = REDIRECT_URI;
            parameters.Scope = SCOPE;

            string authorizationUrl = OAuthUtil.CreateOAuth2AuthorizationUrl(parameters);
            MessageBox.Show(authorizationUrl);
            Console.WriteLine("Please visit the URL in the message box to authorize your OAuth "
              + "request token.  Once that is complete, type in your access code to "
              + "continue...");
            parameters.AccessCode = Console.ReadLine();

            OAuthUtil.GetAccessToken(parameters);
            string accessToken = parameters.AccessToken;
            Console.WriteLine("OAuth Access Token: " + accessToken);

            GOAuth2RequestFactory requestFactory =
                new GOAuth2RequestFactory(null, "MySpreadsheetIntegration-v1", parameters);
            SpreadsheetsService service = new SpreadsheetsService("MySpreadsheetIntegration-v1");
            service.RequestFactory = requestFactory;

            SpreadsheetQuery query = new SpreadsheetQuery();

            SpreadsheetFeed feed = service.Query(query);

            // Iterate through all of the spreadsheets returned
            foreach (SpreadsheetEntry entry in feed.Entries)
            {
                // Print the title of this spreadsheet to the screen
                Console.WriteLine(entry.Title.Text);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```